# Windows Azure Portal login to portal and receive error "We are having trouble logging you into the portal"

Tags: windows, azure, authentication, portal, subscription

1. Open browser
2. Navigate to http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/
3. Select portal top right
4. login with my email address
5. Receive the below error

https://manage.windowsazure.com/Error/Login?getsupport=true&f=255&MSPPError=-2147217320

Receive the error
" We are having trouble logging you into the portal
Please contact Customer Service for assistance."

Using IE or Chrome, incognito or not, cookies cleared or not, cache cleared or not. The problem still exists. Also tried on multiple devices media centre PC, desktop running windows 7, iPhone 5, ipad 3...

Prior to November 2012 I have accessed the windows azure subscription without a problem.

I clicked the customer service link and the australian number is 13 20 58 I have contacted that number explaining that I cannot access my windows azure subscription and each time I login I receive an error. They proceed to redirect me to other support teams where I repeat my details and the problem they either redirect me again or provide a number to call. 
In one case I was redirected to a number that no longer exists. Another I was told to raise a case on the windows azure portal page the same portal page that I receive an error on when logging in, when I asked for alternative options there were none.
So far I've spoke with the msdn support team, windows subscription support, online services, etc and still no resolution. In the latest call to support they have said to raise the issue on the forums so here goes.

Anyways long story short I have probably spent 3+ hours calling Microsoft support explaining the problem, waiting on hold, being redirect, repeating... still I can't access my windows azure subscription

I checked in commerce.microsoft.com and there is a windows azure subscription associated with my email address
Subscription-1
Windows Azure MSDN - Visual Studio Premium

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You can try opening an in-private (IE) / incognito (Chrome) window to ensure you have no live id creds cached anywhere. Then visit [https://manage.windowsazure.com/](https://manage.windowsazure.com/). Unfortunately as this isn't programming-related, the question is not a good fit for stackoverflow.

Comment: Try clearing cookies and cached items from your browser

Comment: Hi David, I totally agree its a question for Microsoft not stackoverflow. However I was instructed by Microsoft support to raise it on the forums so I did. Running out of options to get this fixed.

Using IE or Chrome, incognito or not, cookies cleared or not, cache cleared or not. The problem still exists. Also tried on multiple devices media centre PC, desktop running windows 7, iPhone 5, ipad 3....

Comment: Escalated within Microsoft Support has been resolved.

Case resolution information from Fazal (Support Engineer Windows Azure Subscription Management Support)
"This is what we did to resolve the issue, the Azure subscription is linked to your Live ID so what we did is added your Office 365 ID as a co-admin (management portal access) and delegate (account portal access). This gave your Office 365 account authorization to access your Azure account. The Live ID is still linked to your Azure account but you can completely manage this with your Office 365 account as well."

Comment: I had this - had to use Internet Exploder instead of Chrome. Yay web standards.

Comment: If this got 9 up-votes, and my questions got +30 down-votes, SOF still has a very, very long way to go. Glad your issue was solved.

Comment: Why does Microsoft SUCK so bad? How bad must you be as a tech company to even mess up a login system?

Comment: For anybody still having this problem, I found that logging in with a different browser fixed the issue for me. I can't imagine why. If that doesn't work, maybe try clearing cookies/typical browser stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Some time it's happened wait for while and retry

or just ask azure support in twitter

Answer (score 0):

*Editing for those who are like me and skipped reading the comments (in small font) below the OP's question. This was resolved and was due to the first reason I list below. However, it could (and has) happen in past for other reasons as well, so might as well keep this response here in case it helps someone else out.*

- Try logging at https://portal.azure.com/
- The manage.windowsazure.com isn't even DNS resolvable to any website - I am not sure how you are getting that address (maybe its from some part of Azure IAM pipeline that hasn't been updated) and (more interestingly) how you are able to open that link - Maybe this is something available only in your region ! (but I am stretching here).

Regardless, I also tried to find other instances of similar issues and in general I see this issue is related to cases when the an account has been transitioned to Office 365.

- [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b2375030-ecc7-4460-aac1-12124ee59fb6/windows-azure-portal-login-to-portal-and-receive-error-8220we-are-having-trouble-logging-you-into?forum=windowsazuremanagement) an account was moved and resulted in creation of two accounts with different passwords - solution here was to set the Office 365 account (new account) as a co-admin on the old account that was used to setup the Azure account.
- [Here](http://www.viding.se/?p=62) the account was not provisioned correctly in Azure AD Store and had to be removed and re-created using DirSync
- [Here](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/security/zh-CN/bcb8d97b-0043-46c8-86ee-f7083b21e966/acs20012-the-request-is-not-a-valid-wsfederation-protocol-message?forum=WindowsAzureAD), the problem seems to be related to (the new) Account Provisioning in Azure AD.

In general, it seems this is a problem that might be harder to explain to level 1 support. You might have better mileage speaking to your organizations IT admin and have them check for any inconsistencies that might be similar to those stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing the directory in the URL like so

https://portal.azure.com/@domain.name

For example in case of MS AAD domain

https://portal.azure.com/@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com

In case of custom domain

https://portal.azure.com/@mycompany.com

Sometimes there is some odd behaviour with redirect loops or when you no longer have access to the tenant but you have selected 'last visited' in the Startup directory.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Glad to hear this was resolved by support.  Since this was posted, we made a number of updates to the login process and types of accounts (incl. the addition of MFA).  At TechEd we announced a new portal (video @ http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Windows-Azure/Azure-Preview-portal) if you want to see what is coming.

Comment: This doesn't qualify as an answer. BTW, it's 2018 and I still face the same error and I was pointed to this page from the Microsoft support and I see no helpful answer here. I am disappointed that you (Microsoft) managed to fail even with a simple login process.

Comment: I second what Kevin said. I am having the same issue right now. It baffles me that Microsoft can find a way to irritate me every day, without fail.